# Sierra - App Store Debug Menu

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

How can I enable the Debug Menu in the App Store for Sierra? The `defaults` command no longer seem to turn it on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, the debug menu is removed from Sierra. Try to clear Mac App Store caches to fix some downloading issues.

Launch Terminal and type the following command:

```
 open `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`/com.apple.appstore
```

Move all the files and folders out of com.apple.appstore. Then relaunch Mac App Store. You can delete all the files and folders if Mac App Store get back to work.