# What other apps have secret debug menus?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm aware that [Reminders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262592/reminders-badge-shows-wrong-count-on-different-devices/265114#265114), [Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/what-are-the-purposes-and-safety-to-enable-the-hidden-debug-menu-in-disk-utility), and [App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259149/sierra-app-store-debug-menu) have debug menus. Are there any other apps that have a similar Terminal command for a secret debug menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Reminders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262592/reminders-badge-shows-wrong-count-on-different-devices/265114#265114)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.reminders RemindersDebugMenu -bool true
  ```
- [Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/what-are-the-purposes-and-safety-to-enable-the-hidden-debug-menu-in-disk-utility)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled -bool true
  ```
- [App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259149/sierra-app-store-debug-menu)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
  ```
- Safari (not to be confused with Develop menu which can be enabled in Preferences)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
  ```

  [image]
- iCal

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.iCal IncludeDebugMenu -bool true
  ```
- Contacts

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.Contacts ABShowDebugMenu -bool YES
  ```

Comment: iCal, not to be confused with the newer version Calendar? Or is it still called iCal in the hardware?

Comment: @DonielF The preferences are still called iCal, but I’ve called the app iCal too because it doesn’t seem to be available since the rename to Calendar and the app was changed substantially.

Comment: Ah. I see it's discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58889/234283).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in MacOS Catalina 10.15.7